# Arch Windows dualboot: fdisk only lists liveusb?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, uefi, fdisk

I'm trying to dual boot windows 10 (secureboot disabled, uefi enabled) with arch. I used the disk management utility in windows to set aside some space for linux, but when I boot the liveusb and run `fdisk -l`, only the contents of the liveusb are listed. Which I suppose makes sense, but I'm not sure how to read the system disk and start the mounting step.

To boot into arch at this time, I enter the BIOS and select the USB as a boot option (second item on the list, to windows boot manager). Then I select Arch Linux (archiso UEFI CD).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## EDIT: ANSWER

I have less than 15 reputation, so I can't answer my own question. But I solved the issue. I needed to switch the mode of my SSD drives from RAID to AHCI, this way arch could recognize and mount them. This seems to be a specific issue for my machine, the XPS 9560.